# Difference between Rows Matched and Rows Changed

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a bit confused regarding the executeUpdate command in mysql. I remember reading  that it returns the rows affected. In another place I read that it returns the rows matched. Could anyone kindly clarify the difference between Rows matched and Rows Changed ? And what exactly does executeUpdate return ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rows affected (updated, changed) is what `executeUpdate` returns.

Rows matched is the number of rows that match the provided conditions to update.  If no column values were changed, none are affected.

For example if you had

```
id | name
1  | bob
2  | drew
3  | david
```

And ran

```
UPDATE t1 SET
name = 'drew'
WHERE name LIKE 'd%'
```

two rows would be matched, but only one would be affected.

Comment: my sql is a little rusty and I am having trouble understanding the above statement. `UPDATE tablename SET name= 'drew'` isnt this missing a where clause ? what would the affect of the query be. I would appreciate it if you could kindly explain it a little

Comment: @MistyD no WHERE clause means that *all* rows match. I've edited the answer make its intention clearer. (+1 btw)

Comment: Reading the question again . Why would only one row be affected ? if two rows were matched ?

Comment: @MistyD because one of the rows already has `name = 'drew'`.  If the row does not change, it's not affected